# Independence of $\sigma$-algebra generated by random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, independence

I found this question ([Does $\mathbb{P}$-a.s. convergence preserve independence?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1645814/does-mathbbp-a-s-convergence-preserve-independence/1844173?newreg=9d10b331b4a34e2284994cd782918188)).

There is a sequence of R.V. $\{\xi_n\}$ and $\sigma$-algebra $F$. All $\xi_n$ are independent from $F$.

I'm trying to understand answer by martini. It is not clear why $\sigma(X_n: n \in N)$ is independent from $F$ if each $\sigma(X_n)$ is.

Comment: The answer you are quoting is wrong and I just made a comment there. It is not true that $F$ and $\sigma (X_n: n \in \mathbb n)$ are independent.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d $\pm 1$ with probability $\frac 1 2 $ each then $X,Y,XY$ are pairwise independent but not jointly independent.

Now let $F=\sigma (X), X_1=Y$ and $X_n =XY, n=2,3...$. Then $F$ is independent of $\sigma (X_n)$ for each $n$ but it is not independent of $\sigma (X_1,X_2,...)$.